# How to add multiple Tinymce editor in single page on wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display multiple times Tinymce editor when the button clicked,
I already add one editor using this code:
 `wp_editor( $content, 'editor_id', array( 'textarea_name' => 'faq_content[]' ) );`

output:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPPAQ.png)
When we click on add new button there append a div class with a `wp_editor()` in it. Then
our tinymce editor will not be responsive.